# How can i randomize delay of moving object

Tags: java, android

Recently i added that enemy shoots but unfortunately i cannot randomize delay of Shooting for every object.

Project 60 times in second  :

- update (all code here is connected to this part)
- draw
- sleep

### Fragment of code :

[Fragment of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S82d8.png)

```
    public void createNewEnemyBullet(){
    for(Enemy enemy: enemies){
        EnemyBullet enemyBullet = new EnemyBullet(getResources());
        randomShot = random.nextInt(60-40)+40;

     
        System.out.println("Randomowy shot :"+ randomShot);
        enemyBullet.x = (int) (((enemy.x+enemy.widthEnemy/2)-18)*screenRatioX);
        enemyBullet.y= enemy.y+20;

        enemyBullets.add(enemyBullet);
    }

    System.out.println("\n\n");
}
```

### Screenshot of my result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0iP1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.random()`. It'll be your friend here. Compare (`Math.random() <= epsilon`) the output of `random()` with some number `epsilon` you want as your threshold for making an enemy shooting decision.

If `enemyBullets` is what the UI code uses to draw bullets, you may want to add a `Thread.sleep(Math.random())` to add variable delay in adding them.

Comment: I got random number but how can i do imply this to bullet delay

Comment: i got 5 enemy planes. how can i change bullet speed for each other diffrend

Comment: Use Math.random() 5 times and add each random number generated to the enemyBullet x or y, as desired. Possibly even generate two random numbers per enemy - one for x and one for y.

If that solves it for you, remember to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: if i would use your method it would be same thing as right now using random.nextInt(); How can i change delay of bullet for each of enemy planes?

Comment: could i pm You somewhere? Still dont know excacly how. I mean i understand your idea but how can i relate to those enemies  like if(enemies[0]) and what next . You understand me?

Comment: No need to do that. You are already looping through your enemies. Each `enemy` inside the loop is a different Enemy instance.

Comment: could you post this fragment of code changed like You are saying? I will upvote of course

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lYWlwVp it make those random numbers but its get overwritten

Comment: remember i dont want to change speed but delay of shooting the bullet

Comment: Sorry, I missed the delay part. How about you add a `Thread.sleep(Math.random());` before `enemyBullets.add(enemyBullet);`

Comment: wouldn't it sleep full program?

Comment: It would. Maybe paste your UI code as well. It'll make it easier to help you out.

Comment: i tried and its sleep full program and nothing changes

Comment: i will post video from game

Comment: i added randomShot to change when enemy is shot so it changes like in waves

Answer (score 0):

Solution for generating random delay of bullet is to change this delay when a enemy starship is shot.